# Showing the expectation of uniform r.v is $\frac{a + b}{2} $

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is uniform over $(a,b)$, then $\mathbb{E} \{ X \} = \frac{a + b}{2}$.

I am given that

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X \} = \int X P^X(dx) $$

where $P^X$ is the distribution of $X$.

I am confused as this definition. Can someone explain to me what $P^X(dx) $ means?

Comment: I think $\int X P^{X}(dx)$ is just the Lebesgue integral of the measurable function $X$ with respect to the measure $P^{X}$ defined by $P^{X}(A) = P(X^{-1}(A))$ ($A \subseteq \Bbb R$ a Borel set), where $P$ is the probability measure on the domain of $X$.

Comment: $P^X$ is the distribution of $X$ means that $F(x) = P( (- \infty, x] ) = \int_{-\infty}^y f(y) dy  $ where $f$ is the density of $f$. Is this correct? so that in this case we can write $E(X) = \int x f(x) dx $ ?

Comment: Do you know the density function $f(x)$ of UNIF(a,b)?